# SKPaymentTransactionObserver warning on submitting IOS In-App purchase product in App store with Ionic 2 App

Tags: ios, ionic2, ionic3, skpaymenttransaction

I am trying to submit Ionic 2 Application with in-app purchase in apple App store. I am getting the below `SKPaymentTransactionObserver` method warning in App store promotion section. How to overcome it?

[image]